# How to properly construct a OAuth2 GET request using typescript/angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, autodesk-forge

I have the following GET endpoint:

`<a href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsampleapp.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback%3Ffoo%3Dbar&scope=data:read">Click here to grant access to your data!</a>`

**The href contains the following:**

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize`
This is the endpoint URI

`response_type=code`

`client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE`
client ID.

`redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsampleapp.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback%3Ffoo%3Dbar`
This is the URL-encoded callback URL

is it possible to construct a post request  using the above and subscribe the return value?

any clue or references will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend getting that close to the protocol implementation itself, but look for a library that can help you with that. Try out [`angular-auth-oidc-client`](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), this should get you on track.